# saveMany() not storing data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Given the following models:

```
Car Model
- parts: hasMany(Parts::class)

Part Model
- car: belongsTo(Car::class)
```

Running

```
Car::find(1)->parts()->saveMany(Part::hydrate($request->parts));
```

properly returns a list of Parts, 3 have id, one does not, so that's 3 models that need to be updated and one needs to be inserted.
However looking at my database, not a single row is inserted and issuing `dd(Car::find(1)->parts)` returns an empty array. `createMany` works, but that does not update the models that have an `id` - instead it creates new ones.
From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models),

> If you need to save multiple related models, you may use the saveMany method
>
> ...
>
> the difference between `save` and `create` is that `save` accepts a full Eloquent model instance while create accepts a plain PHP `array`

So what is the reason `createMany` works but `saveMany` does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a misuse of `Post::hydrate`. The `hydrate` function returns a collection of models that are marked as if they're coming from the database. Since after hydration nothing is changed, `save()` is being ignored because there are no changes made to them.
Furthermore, `saveMany()` doesn't care for the `id` specified and it creates a new objects indiscriminately. In the end I moved validation to the related model and do a `delete()/createMany()` on each update.

Answer (score 0):

You have explained it yourself, via your quote from the docs.

`saveMany()` uses eloquent models, this would be great for updating already existing parts. It does not work with generic arrays which I assume `$request->parts` is from your front-end.

`createMany()` uses generic arrays, since your `$request->parts` (Again I'm assuming) is an array it passes.

Comment: `$request->parts` is indeed an array, however `Part::hydrate($request->parts)` returns a collection of `Part` models from the input. Now, I can iterate over that collection and call `save()` on each object but with thousands of parts this is a very poor way of doing this. I just don't know why `createMany` works with an array and `saveMany` does not with a collection of models when the documentation states it is the intended way to use them.

Comment: Could you try hydrating them before plugging it in to the saveMany function? `$hydrated = Part::hydrate($request->parts)` then plug in $hydrated? just to see if it's any different?

Comment: Just tried iterating over `$hydrated` and calling `->save()` on each instance - none seem to work. The issue is probably coming from somewhere else (possibly because I'm not running validation on the input yet...)